# Excel vba: creating folders doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create folders in a test folder through vba, but it doesn't work. I can't figure out why - the commands seem legal.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createFolders()
    Dim homePath As String
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim foldersNumber As Long
    homePath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(1, 2).Value & "\"
    folderName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Cells(2, 2).Value

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To foldersNumber
            If Not fso.FolderExists(homePath & folderName & i) Then
                    fso.CreateFolder (homePath & folderName & i)
            Else
                MsgBox ("Folder exits")
            End If


    Next

    MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

Comment: foldersNumber seems to be undefined. It is declared but never given a value, I suspect the for loop is never run.

Comment: @ AndyW Thanks, I didn't notice that, was concentrating on a `fso` part.